# How to test blocking function?

Tags: c#, nunit

How do I test if a function blocks indefinitely in a particular situation?

```
[Test]
public void BlockingTest()
{
    blockingFunction();    // this function halts execution indefinitely

    Assert.Fail("Execution not halted.");
}
```

Supposing `blockingFunction()` is a function waiting for something to happen, that should block execution until a particular event occurs, and the test supposes this event to never occurr.

**EDIT**: what I'm actually looking for is an elegant solution, possibly without having to explicitly wait a hardcoded time before reporting success.

Posting my current situation for reference:

```
[Test]
public void BlockTest() {
    BytesStream bs = new BytesStream();
    bs.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2 }, 0, 2);

    var buff2 = new byte[2];
    bs.Read(buff2, 0, 2);

    bool dataWritten = false;

    new Thread(() => {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            Thread.Sleep(0); // ensure the parent thread execute next line

        dataWritten = true;
        bs.Write(new byte[] { 3, 4 }, 0, 2);
    }).Start();

    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, bs.Read(buff2, 0, 2), "#1");

    if(!dataWritten)
        Assert.Fail("#2");

    Assert.AreEqual(new byte[] { 3, 4 }, buff2, "#3");
}
```

Comment: Just wait an infinite amount of time, then you'll have proven it never returned. I don't think you can do this, but if you can explain more about the code there may be another way.

Comment: Simplifying: I have a queue, a producer writes some data to the queue, and a consumer reads it. If there is no producer, the consumer will have to wait indefinitely.

I have patched the test by spawning a producer thread and waiting a few instants before actually sending something to the queue unblocking the consumer, I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I test if a function blocks indefinitely in a particular situation?

This is called the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  It is provably impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe let your function execute by a Threadpool object and see if it returns within a specified timespan, like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void BlockingTest()
    {
        AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        BlockingFunctionHelper(ev);    
        // specify time out in ms, thus here: wait 1 s
        Assert.IsTrue(ev.WaitOne(1000), "Execution not halted.");
        ev.Dispose();
    }

    private void BlockingFunctionHelper(AutoResetEvent ev)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((e) =>
            {
                BlockingFunction(); // this function halts execution indefinitely
                ((AutoResetEvent) e).Set();
            }, ev);
    }
```

Comment: This is quite like what I'm doing right now, I'm looking for something more elegant. Possibly without blocking the test execution for more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: If you specify `ev.WaitOne(50, ...)` then you test if the function returns within 50 ms.  I did a quick test (by using a sleep of 500 or 5000 ms) in the `BlockingFunction()` with the code in my answer and it seems to test it correctly. But I don't know how to make it more elegant. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's almost totally impossible to happen, but supposing for some reason the child thread takes longer than 50ms to be executed, the test fails incorrectly.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asserting that `ev.WaitOne` returns `false`? If `ev.WaitOne` returns true, then the blocking function returned.

Comment: Yes that is possible. The test as implemented in my answer can test if the blocking function not blocks for some specified time. But it is hard to test what you want, timings may differ from time to time (depending on what your machine is executing in parallel) and from machine to machine. I hope that someone else has a better answer for you. I'm also interested because sometimes I've similar test cases.

Comment: @bruce965: If you're worried about the thread delay, have the thread set an event before it starts, and have an assert check that event. Something like `Assert.IsTrue(startedEvent.WaitOne(1000), "Thread failed to start.");` That way, at least you know that the blocking test wasn't actually performed.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your question. Your test method will wait an indefinite amount of time and fail should the `blockingFunction` return any sooner. Just let it run and fix the code should it ever fail.

---

Now to answer the real problem here: what do you **really** want to test?

Is it actually a requirement that the `blockingFunction` blocks execution? I'd presume that if it would consume queue items *without* blocking execution, it'd be even better – but your fictional test would fail then.

In other words: I assume it's not important that your `blockingFunction` blocks, you should test *business* logic and not technical behavior, *unless* there is an actual use case.

Like if your consumer were to terminate if no item would be generated within `t` seconds, then you could wait for `t` seconds and fail if it returned any sooner.

If you wanted to test whether your consumer "wakes up" after being idle for a while, you could wait for `n` seconds and then generate an item. Fail it the consumer does something earlier, and fail if it doesn't consume after you generate your item.

Only you can truly answer this question, for we don't know what you **actually** want to test here. I hope I managed to spell that out in a helpful way.

Answer (score 0):

One idea if you have a trigger that should wake up the call:

In thread a:

1. Call the blocking function
2. For one second or maybe a little bit more, consume 100 % CPU
3. Let the thread return

In thread b:

1. Use the OS API to find the running status of thread a. Verify that it is currently sleeping.
2. Trigger the event that makes thread a return from the blocking function
3. Use the OS API to find the running status of thread b. Verify that it is currently running
4. Synchronize with thread a